# Gitlab with SAML redirects Pages to the gitlab-root

Tags: gitlab, saml

Having a GitLab-CE installed on-premise behind the Traefik.
Gitlab was taken from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab as is without any modifications.
SAML authentication against GSuite is used to get users into the GitLab.

The problems are:
Pages works only for personal users accounts and only for `everyone` in security settings.
When I'm trying to access protected page I'm being redirected to the root of the gitlab after the successful authorization.

Here is the config for Pages:

```
- GITLAB_PAGES_ENABLED=true
- GITLAB_PAGES_DOMAIN=pages.gitlab.domain.xyz
- GITLAB_PAGES_ACCESS_CONTROL=true
- GITLAB_PAGES_ACCESS_CONTROL_SERVER=https://gitlab.domain.xyz
- GITLAB_PAGES_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=asdfasdf
- GITLAB_PAGES_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=asdfasdf
- GITLAB_PAGES_ACCESS_REDIRECT_URI=https://pagesauth.gitlab.domain.xyz/auth
```

Traefik part:

```
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=gitlab
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.gitlab.frontend.rule=Host:gitlab.domain.xyz,pages.gitlab.domain.xyz,pagesauth.gitlab.domain.xyz
      - traefik.backend.healthcheck.hostname=gitlab
      - traefik.gitlab.port=80
```

Gitlab app for the pages auth:

```
Callback URL:  http://pagesauth.gitlab.domain.xyz/auth
Trusted: No
Scopes: API
```